Allow moderators to customize the first paragraph under "Get answers to practical, detailed questions" on the tour page
Currently, the first paragraph of the tour under the heading "Get answers to practical, detailed questions" says:

Focus on questions about an actual problem you have faced. Include details about what you have tried and exactly what you are trying to do.

Now that makes some sense for a site like Stack Overflow, but not for a lot of other sites. For example, that makes no sense for Politics, Puzzling, Code Golf and Coding Challenges, Philosophy, Science Fiction & Fantasy, History, Skeptics, Lifehacks, or Music Fans. I could probably think of more.
However, moderators are unable to customize this paragraph for their site. While the typical process to adjust fields mods can't change is to escalate them to the CM team, it'd be nice if mods could edit this section directly. Could this be changed?

@Rubén Ummm...That's talking about the description of the site in the communities tab. This is talking about the tour page. Those are different.

While the specific item to be changed is different, the process is exactly the same.

@Rubén Why do you think that? And for the record I posted on a sites meta and they said “we can’t do anything try a feature Req on main meta

Add Aviation to that list. We do get quite a few actual problems, but a not-insignificant number of questions are out of pure interest in the subject.

I agree with Starship, in that the suggested dupe doesn't appear to be about the same issue at all. This may once again be how these things are done on Meta, but IMHO a better method would be to create a Q&A that talks about implementing changes to the default sites in general.

This is actually probably a better duplicate (see the last paragraph of the answer).

The others are support questions asking essentially "How to do X"? This one is a direct request asking "Let me do X". This is different. Reopened.

Rubén's advice on following the CM escalation process is how we've always handled uneditable sections of our site (AFAIK). I personally would urge for a more abstract question of "please let everything be editable by mods" -- however, as a mod, seeing the 1000 different Markdown flavours SE employs on the backend makes me think such a request would be hard declined.

@Peilonrayz This is request to allow the mods to customize it so that an escalation is not necessary.

Yes, I've read the question.
